# QOpenGLWindow QPainter Mixed rendering

Tags: qt, opengl

I just do like this link:
http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2014/11/20/qt-weekly-20-completing-the-offering-qopenglwindow-and-qrasterwindow/?utm_source=tuicool

I do as the link say.But I can't get the right result.Only have the background color.What's Wrong whith my code?

My code:

```
class Render : public QOpenGLWindow
{
public:
    Render();
    ~Render();
protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int  w ,int h);
     QOpenGLFunctions * f;
     QOpenGLBuffer * triangle;
     QOpenGLVertexArrayObject * vao;
     QOpenGLShaderProgram * program;
      QMatrix4x4 mv,p;
      QTimer * time;
      float rota;
     //QPainter * painter;

};
```

---

```
GLfloat tri[] =
{
    0.0f,1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,
     1.0f,1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,
     1.0f,0.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,

};
Render::Render()
{
    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
    format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
    format.setVersion(3,3);
    format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
    setFormat(format);
    time = new QTimer;
    connect(time,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(update()));
    time->start(50);
    rota = 0;


}

Render::~Render()
{

}
void Render::initializeGL()
{
//    f = QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->versionFunctions<QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core>();
//    f->initializeOpenGLFunctions();

    f = context()->functions();


    program =  new QOpenGLShaderProgram;
    program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex,
                                     "#version 330 core \n\
                                     layout(location = 0) in vec4 vertex;\
            uniform mat4 mvp;\
                                     void main() \
            {\
                gl_Position = mvp * vertex;\
             }");

    program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment,
                                     "#version 330 core \n\
                                     out vec4 fragColor;\
            void main() \
    { \
        fragColor = vec4(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);\
    }");
    program->link();

    vao = new QOpenGLVertexArrayObject;
    vao->create();
    vao->bind();
    triangle = new QOpenGLBuffer(QOpenGLBuffer::VertexBuffer);
    triangle->create();
    triangle->bind();

    triangle->setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::StaticDraw);
    triangle->allocate(tri,sizeof(tri));
    program->enableAttributeArray(0);
    program->setAttributeBuffer(0,GL_FLOAT,0,4,0);
    f->glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);


}
void Render::resizeGL(int w ,int h)
{
    p.setToIdentity();
     p.perspective(35.0f,float(w)/float(h),1.0f,30.0f);
}
void Render::paintGL()
{
    program->bind();
    f->glClearColor(0.5,0.5f,0.5f,1.0f);
    f->glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    f->glViewport(0,0,width(),height());

    mv.setToIdentity();

    mv.lookAt(QVector3D(0.0f,0.0f,5.0f),QVector3D(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f),QVector3D(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
    mv.rotate(0.5+rota,0,1,0);
    program->setUniformValue("mvp",p*mv);
    vao->bind();
    f->glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3);
    rota=rota+1.5;
    rota=rota>360.0?0:rota;


    QPainter pp(this);

    pp.drawText(10,20,"dsdsds");
    update();
}
```

Comment: If you still have this issue try removing the format.setVersion(..) line and also disabling depth test during the painter commands.

Answer (score 0):

When I needed to do this I overrode paintEvent and used `QPainter::beginNativePainting ();`/`QPainter::endNativePainting ();`

```
void Render::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{

    QPainter p(this);
    p.beginNativePainting ();
    makeCurrent ();
    //restore and save state so they don't interact
    glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT|GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    paintGL ();
    glClear (GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT|GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDisable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    p.endNativePainting ();

    //other painting
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I have try your way,but I  can not get the result which QPainter render,just have the triangle which render by opengl.I use the new class "QOpenGLWindow"of Qt 5.4.

Comment: it works for me with Qt 5.0; are you doing it where `paintGL` is?

Comment: I don't use 'paintGL' , I put my opengl code in 'paint' function,and put 'paint' funtion in which your code put. I am sorry for my English.I hope you can understand my meaning.

Comment: lf l use paintGL and paintEvent  together like you paintGL will be called twice,because QOpenGLWindow auto call paintGL like QGLWidget do.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could resolve it by releasing the vertex buffer before using QPainter. So you might want to try
    vao->release();
    triangle->release();
    program->release();
before initializing QPainter.

Answer (score 0):

This is what has worked for me in "QOpenGLWidget ". I did not need to put the OpenGL code between "beginNativePainting()" and "beginNativePainting()" Qpainter function calls. I did not need to override the paintEvent ... Which is similar to what's in the link you shared.

1) In the constructor of the "QOpenGLWidget" set the format to "CompatibilityProfile"
eg:

```
QSurfaceFormat  format;
format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CompatibilityProfile);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
this->setFormat(format);
```

2) In your Game Loop Function 
make sure to release the program, VAO, VBO, & EBO after you are done with the OpenGL code and before calling your Qpainter and using it at the very end of the function.
eg:

```
VAO.release();
VBO->release();
EBO->release();
m_program->release();
QPainter painter(this);
painter.begin(this);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
painter.drawText(10,20,"dsdsds");
painter.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Qt 5.8. The solution was not only to call

```
vao->release();
triangle->release();
program->release();
```

as Daniel suggested, but also to call

```
program->disableAttributeArray(0);
```

before the shader program is released.

So basically anything that is bound or enabled on the GPU needs to be disabled or released.